# Custom Notification tray doesn't work for some phones

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-custom-view

I am working on an application which sends device to device push notification. I have created a custom notification layout which has a heading, message and two buttons (Accept and Reject). When device B receives a notification from Device A, for some phones it works perfectly, but in some phones the notification tray fails to display the title, message and buttons. It just shows a blank notification tray. Its not an error, but the custom layout doesn't load for some phones. It works perfectly in Moto G5s plus (Android 7.1.1), but doesn't work for RedMi Note 5 Pro, same API level (Android 7.1.1). Can anyone help me with this?

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Map<String, String> remoteMessageData = remoteMessage.getData();

    String remoteMessageType = remoteMessageData.get("type");


        String message = remoteMessageData.get("message") + ". Please Confirm?";
        String profilePhoto = remoteMessageData.get("profile_photo");
        String notificationUID = remoteMessageData.get("notification_uid");
        String userUID = remoteMessageData.get("user_uid");

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.layout_custom_notification);

        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.textNotificationMessage, message);

        remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.eIntercomProfilePic, getBitmapFromURL(profilePhoto));

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.namma_apartment_notification)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setCustomBigContentView(remoteViews)
                .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND))
                .setPriority(PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .build();

        int mNotificationID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

        Intent acceptButtonIntent = new Intent("accept_button_clicked");
        acceptButtonIntent.putExtra("Notification_Id", mNotificationID);
        acceptButtonIntent.putExtra("Notification_UID", notificationUID);
        acceptButtonIntent.putExtra("User_UID", userUID);
        PendingIntent acceptPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 123, acceptButtonIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.buttonAccept, acceptPendingIntent);

        Intent rejectButtonIntent = new Intent("reject_button_clicked");
        rejectButtonIntent.putExtra("Notification_UID", notificationUID);
        rejectButtonIntent.putExtra("Notification_Id", mNotificationID);
        rejectButtonIntent.putExtra("User_UID", userUID);
        PendingIntent rejectPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 123, rejectButtonIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.buttonReject, rejectPendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    /*To support Android Oreo Devices and higher*/
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                    getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id), "Namma Apartments Channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            Objects.requireNonNull(notificationManager).createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you talking about Oreo or above version. Oreo can not support notification for notification you need to create channel for that like below :

```
 private void sendMyNotification(String message,String title) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        Uri soundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel=new NotificationChannel("my_notification","n_channel",NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX);
            notificationChannel.setDescription("description");
            notificationChannel.setName("Channel Name");
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.listlogo)
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.tlogo))
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(soundUri)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX)
                    .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                    .setChannelId("my_notification")
                    .setColor(Color.parseColor("#3F5996"));
            //.setProgress(100,50,false);
            notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
```